# Problem with UUID

Tags: 14.04, fstab, uuid

I have tried those tutorial on this website base on the disk drive for `uuid` is not yet ready or not present.

I am trying to boot a live USB also and the message is no default or ui configuration found.

I have tried some tutorial using terminal and its not really working. I have tried some command on terminal but some command is not working like:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and it show a different code that is not matching with in their tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID is specific to *your circumstance*. Yours *should* be different to the one in the tutorial.

Use `sudo blkid` to find your partitions' UUIDs and use those to identify which partitions you want to mount.

The post should state all of this. If it doesn't, let us know where it is so it can be fixed.

---

And on a side note, if you boot to a Live USB and go to edit `/etc/fstab`, you will edit the Live version of that file, not the one saved on your harddisk. You will need to mount the disk, and then edit its version.

Comment: i used the `blkid` and this is the response            `/dev/sda1: UUID="83924586-165f-47cc-86eb-aed3d468f231" TYPE="ext4"` what should i do then? the uuid on that showed on the start up and said that is not ready or missing is this one  `04f27941-b3ad-4599-b95f-03b0a2c2cb83`

Comment: You use that UUID instead of the one the tutorial is suggesting... But if you let me know *what* you're following, I can be more specific.

Comment: But honestly, it might be worth abandoning this tutorial and just [running Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a LiveCD. It should handle all this nonsense for you.

Comment: i dont have a live cd here only the usb how can i change that uui to the one that is showing on the terminal?

Comment: Live USB will do too. Just follow the "2nd option".

Comment: i am trying the boot repair now i will post the update here maybe i accidentaly damage my hdd when im trying to install the kali linux on vbox?

Comment: The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)    this is what i get from the boot repair

Comment: It has told you what to do.

Comment: the problem is i dunno how to edit that can you pls help me?